# Create custom own oauth provider in node express 4

Tags: node.js, express, oauth

Is there any working sever implementation of custom oauth provider. I tried [node-oauth2-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-oauth2-server) library. But couldn't make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you tried to get node-oauth2-server to work and ran into issues, you could ask specific questions here about the problems you encountered, but until you do this, "I couldn't make it work" is completely unactionable.